# Can't get $(date +%F) set as environment variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I would like to create an environment variable that will output the current date. I have added the following to ~/.pam_environment:

```
TODAY=$(date +%F)
```

[Apparently](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables), you have to log out after changing ~/.pam_environment. I did that but

```
echo $TODAY
```

outputs a blank line.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`~/.pam_environment` is not a script file. Use `~/.profile` instead:

```
export TODAY=$(date +%F)
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the "quotes" Here is a [Cool Link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/) for more examples.

```
TODAY= date +"%F"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I tried experimenting a bit and added the following to ~/.pam_environment:  `TODAY=date +"%F"`  `TODAYS=$(date +"%F")`  `NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")`  None of these are working

Comment: @ScottGoodgame That's not the problem. It is not generally necessary to quote `%`, and although the reference you provided follows this style, it does not actually say one has to do so. Try some examples from that page without quotes (e.g., `date +%m-%d-%y`). It works fine. In addition, `TODAY= date +"%F"` actually runs `date +"%F"` with `TODAY` set to the empty string in its environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ export DATE=`date +"%F"`
$ echo $DATE
2014-05-30
```